# Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args) throws error "Unvalid URI: The URI is Empty"

Tags: c#, activator

The program loads dll files from a subfolder. In debug in Visual Studio Professional 2022 it runs, as it should, but in release mode the following line throws the inner exception "Invalid URI: The URI is Empty"

```cs
OB = Activator.CreateInstance(t, con.getConnection());
```

`OB` is an `Object` variable
`t` is a type variable, which is "service", a class I wrote and is defined in the dlls
`con.getConnection()` is a `Databaseconnection`

It also works for prior dlls but for new ones it throws the error.

I compared the working dlls with the broken ones.

Comment: So your "service", a class you wrote, throws an exception in its constructor that accepts a DatabaseConnection? Or your `con.getConnection()`, which is not shown, fails to return a DatabaseConnection?

Comment: con.getConnection() works for other dlls, so it shouldn't be the problem (the command is in an iteration through all dlls in the subfolder) and the broken dll is a copy of another dll, adapted to the new topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem on my own. My program pointed on the wrong Database in Release Mode, where the URI is saved, which occure the error